# Weighted Least Squares by lm-function vs. manual calculation

Tags: r, regression, least-squares, weighted-regression

I am trying to manually calculate beta-coefficients using **Weighted Least Squares**, which are given by:

[image]

X should comprise only one variable and the coefficients should include an intercept. I tried it as follows:

```
set.seed(1)
x = as.matrix(mtcars$wt)
y = as.matrix(mtcars$mpg)
w = runif(length(x))

(t(cbind(1,x)) %*%  diag(w) %*% cbind(1,x))^(-1) %*% 
     t(cbind(1,x)) %*%  diag(w) %*%  y
```

This leads to:

```
         [,1]
[1,] 38.92461
[2,] 11.52764
```

However, the lm-Funktion leads to different results:

```
lm(y~x, weights = w)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, weights = w)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     37.896       -5.437
```

I am quite sure it must have something to do with the `cbind(1,x)`-part, as `(t(cbind(x)) %*%  diag(w) %*% cbind(x))^(-1) %*% t(cbind(x)) %*%  diag(w) %*%  y` leads to the same results as `lm(y~x -1, weights = w)`. Does anyone see what I did wrong while trying to calculate the coefficients manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of them return the same results.

Set $A=X^T WX$.
When computing the fitted values $\hat{\beta}_{WLS}$, the first half of the expression is the *inverse* of $A$. However, as in your code above, literally putting an exponent of $(-1)$ will simply perform $\frac{1}{A_{ij}}$ to every element $A_{ij}$ of the matrix.

Instead, to find the inverse of the matrix in R, simply type solve(A).
With these changes the results of the Weighted Regression manually and in R will match.

Hope this helps.